# Calling function from React container results in JSON object values becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

[Posting this for a coworker.]

I have a function in a React container that accepts a JSON object when the user submits a React form. The object is copied using Lodash's cloneDeep. This copied object is then passed to another function called `generateFormDataJson`. I noticed a problem regarding undefined `languageIds` in `generateFormDataJson` and did some investigating. This is the code block that calls `generateFormDataJson`:

```
onSubmitPage(values) {
    console.log("VALUES", values);
    let deepCopiedValues = _.cloneDeep(values);
    console.log("DEEP COPIED VALUES", deepCopiedValues);
    let jsonValues = this.generateFormDataJson(deepCopiedValues);
    this.props.submitRegistration(jsonValues).then(() => {
        //console.log("Form has been submitted.");
    });
}
```

Using this code block yields the following result.

[image: Copied Values]

Seeing that the `languageIds` in the copied object were undefined but the original's were not I replaced the copied object with the original in the `generateFormDataJson` function call.

```
onSubmitPage(values) {
    console.log("VALUES", values);
    let deepCopiedValues = _.cloneDeep(values);
    console.log("DEEP COPIED VALUES", deepCopiedValues);
    let jsonValues = this.generateFormDataJson(values);
    this.props.submitRegistration(jsonValues).then(() => {
      //console.log("Form has been submitted.");
    });
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Original Values]

My question is why would the object that is passed to `generateFormDataJson` have undefined `languageIds` while the object that isn't passed doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried doing a shallow copy and seeing if you have the same problem? `let deepCopiedValues = {...values}`.

Comment: In the second one languages has undefined elements then you deep copy and the languages array is populated?  Doesn't seem possible...

Comment: Shallow copying the values got the `languageIds` into the next function. I just need to extract them from the additional { } that were used to make the copy.

Comment: What version of lodash you are using?